# Focusout and click button don't work with childs element's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of div, each div with a button. When I click a button a text is displayed, and when I click out, the info hides with focus out function. If I have a button opened and I want to click a parent button, it's work's well, the button that was opened closes and the new button that I pressed open at the same time. The problem is when I want to do this action with a button that is next, it's don't do the two things and the same time (focus out and click the new button). Live example to check it: https://www.lagaleramagazine.es/

```js
$(".p1").hide();
$(".p1-img").hide();

$(".btn1").click(function() {
  if ($.trim($(this).text()) === 'Más detalles') {
    $(this).text('Menos detalles');
  } else {
    $(this).text('Más detalles');
  }

  $(this).focusout(function() {
    $(".p1").hide();
    $(".p1-img").hide();
    $(this).text('Más detalles');
  });
  var $p1 = $(this).next(".p1").toggle();
  var $p1img = $(this).parents().eq(4).find(".p1-img").toggle();


  $(".p1").not($p1).hide();
  $(".p1-img").not($p1img).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="event-56092" class="ect-list-post ect-featured-event  data-parent-post-id=" 56053 ""="">
  <div class="ect-list-post-left ">
    <div class="ect-list-img" style="background-image:url('https://www.lagaleramagazine.es/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/50008823_1936412149789348_6701274349090897920_n-1024x715.jpg');background-size:cover;background-position:center center;">
      <a href="https://www.lagaleramagazine.es/agenda/vi-escuelas-deportivas-para-mayores/2019-02-25/" title="Imagen del evento" alt="Magazine 1" rel="bookmark">
        <div class="ect-list-date">
          <div class="ect-date-area default-schedule">
            <span class="ev-day">25</span>
            <span class="ev-mo">febrero</span>
            <span class="ev-yr">2019</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ect-list-post-right">
    <div class="ect-list-post-right-table">
      <div class="ect-list-description">
        <h2 class="ect-list-title">
          <a class="ect-event-url" href="https://www.lagaleramagazine.es/agenda/vi-escuelas-deportivas-para-mayores/2019-02-25/" title="VI Escuelas Deportivas para Mayores" rel="bookmark">VI Escuelas Deportivas para Mayores</a>
        </h2>
        <button class="btn1 button-more svg">Más detalles</button>
        <div class="p1" style="display: none;">
          <div class="ect-event-content">
            <p>Desde el lunes 21 de enero y hasta el martes 18 de junio, todos los socios de los Centros Municipales de Mayores que participan en la XXIII Campaña de Atención al Mayor, podrán inscribirse en las diferentes actividades de la VI Escuelas Deportivas
              para mayores. Se impartirán clases de pádel, tenis de mesa, petanca, rutas...</p>
            <a href="https://www.lagaleramagazine.es/agenda/vi-escuelas-deportivas-para-mayores/2019-02-25/" class="ect-events-read-more" rel="bookmark">Ir al evento »</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="p1-venue">
        <div class="ect-list-venue  default-venue">
          <span class="ect-icon">
                        <i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </span>
          <span class="ect-venue-details ect-address">
                        <a href="https://www.lagaleramagazine.es/lugar/area-de-atencion-al-mayor-ayuntamiento-de-badajoz/" title="Area de atención al Mayor , Ayuntamiento de Badajoz">Area de atención al Mayor , Ayuntamiento de Badajoz</a>,
                        <span class="tribe-address">
                            <span class="tribe-locality">Badajoz</span>
          <span class="tribe-delimiter">,</span>
          <abbr class="tribe-region tribe-events-abbr" title="Badajoz">Badajoz</abbr>
          <span class="tribe-country-name">España</span>
          </span>
          </span>
          <span class="ect-google">
                        <a class="tribe-events-gmap" href="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=Badajoz+Badajoz+Espa%C3%B1a" title="Click para ver mapa de Google" target="_blank">+ Google Map</a>
                    </span>
          <div class="ect-rate-area">
            <span class="ect-rate-icon">
                            <i class="fa fa-money" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </span>
            <span class="ect-rate">Gratuito</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you can remove the focusout functionality and use `click` event only since its more accessible. Please check the example below.

**Note**: The reason why focusout is not working for you is that you are targeting a global class `.p1` and hiding it, which is basically hiding the other p tags as well.

```js
$(".btn1").click(function() {

  if ($.trim($(this).text()) === 'Más detalles') {
    $(this).text('Menos detalles');
  } else {
    $(this).text('Más detalles');
  }
  
  var $p1 = $(this).next(".p1");
  var $p1img = $(this).parents().eq(4).find(".p1-img");

  $p1.toggle();
  $p1img.toggle();

  $(".p1").not($p1).hide();
  $(".p1-img").not($p1img).hide();
  
});
```

```css
.p1,
.p1-img {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="event-55758" class="ect-list-post ect-featured-event  data-parent-post-id=" 51063 ""="">
  <div class="ect-list-post-left ">
    <div class="ect-list-img" style="background-image:url('https://www.lagaleramagazine.es/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/timthumb.jpg');background-size:cover;background-position:center center;">
      <a href="https://www.lagaleramagazine.es/agenda/exposicion-16-personajes-que-maravillan-y-miguel-de-cervantes/2019-02-26/" title="Imagen del evento" alt="Magazine 1" rel="bookmark">
        <div class="ect-list-date">
          <div class="ect-date-area default-schedule"> <span class="ev-day">26</span> <span class="ev-mo">febrero</span> <span class="ev-yr">2019</span></div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ect-list-post-right">
    <div class="ect-list-post-right-table">
      <div class="ect-list-description">
        <h2 class="ect-list-title"><a class="ect-event-url" href="https://www.lagaleramagazine.es/agenda/exposicion-16-personajes-que-maravillan-y-miguel-de-cervantes/2019-02-26/" title="Exposición :  “16 personajes que maravillan y … Miguel de Cervantes”." rel="bookmark">Exposición :  “16 personajes que maravillan y … Miguel de Cervantes”.</a></h2>
        <button class="btn1 button-more svg">Más detalles</button>
        <div class="p1" style="display: none;">
          <div class="ect-event-content">
            <p>El próximo 11 de enero, se inaugurará en la&nbsp;Biblioteca Pública del Estado "Bartolomé J. Gallardo" de Badajoz&nbsp;, esta exposición que traza la vida literaria de Miguel de Cervantes(1547-1616), a través de un recorrido por su propia
              obra y acompañado de otros 16 personajes que conmemoran la muerte del autor, incluyendo la presencia del novelista en...</p> <a href="https://www.lagaleramagazine.es/agenda/exposicion-16-personajes-que-maravillan-y-miguel-de-cervantes/2019-02-26/"
              class="ect-events-read-more" rel="bookmark">Ir al evento »</a></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="p1-venue">
        <div class="ect-list-venue  default-venue"><span class="ect-icon"><i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i></span> <span class="ect-venue-details ect-address"><span class="tribe-address"><span class="tribe-locality">Badajoz</span><span class="tribe-delimiter">,</span><abbr class="tribe-region tribe-events-abbr"
            title="Badajoz">Badajoz</abbr><span class="tribe-country-name">España</span></span>
          </span><span class="ect-google"><a class="tribe-events-gmap" href="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=Badajoz+Badajoz+Espa%C3%B1a" title="Click para ver mapa de Google" target="_blank">+ Google Map</a></span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- second -->
<div id="event-58349" class="ect-list-post ect-simple-event  data-parent-post-id=" 58345 ""="">
  <div class="ect-list-post-left ">
    <div class="ect-list-img" style="background-image:url('https://www.lagaleramagazine.es/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/cropped-32396-vegetables-1920x1200-photography-wallpaper.jpg');background-size:cover;background-position:center center;">
      <a href="https://www.lagaleramagazine.es/agenda/come-con-la-cabeza-no-con-la-boca-charlas-para-ninos/2019-02-26/" title="Imagen del evento" alt="Magazine 1" rel="bookmark">
        <div class="ect-list-date">
          <div class="ect-date-area default-schedule"> <span class="ev-day">26</span> <span class="ev-mo">febrero</span> <span class="ev-yr">2019</span></div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ect-list-post-right">
    <div class="ect-list-post-right-table">
      <div class="ect-list-description">
        <h2 class="ect-list-title"><a class="ect-event-url" href="https://www.lagaleramagazine.es/agenda/come-con-la-cabeza-no-con-la-boca-charlas-para-ninos/2019-02-26/" title="Come con la cabeza, no con la boca – Charlas para niños" rel="bookmark">Come con la cabeza, no con la boca – Charlas para niños</a></h2>
        <button class="btn1 button-more svg"><span>Más detalles</span></button>
        <div class="p1" style="display: none;">
          <div class="ect-event-content">
            <p>Fundación CB lanza de nuevo una campaña para educar y concienciar a los niños y padres sobre la importancia de seguir unos hábitos alimenticios saludables. Por la mañana se ofrecerán las charlas a los alumnos y por la tarde a los padres interesados
              en ampliar conocimientos sobre buenos alimentos, enfermedades relacionadas con una mala alimentación,...</p> <a href="https://www.lagaleramagazine.es/agenda/come-con-la-cabeza-no-con-la-boca-charlas-para-ninos/2019-02-26/" class="ect-events-read-more"
              rel="bookmark">Ir al evento »</a></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="p1-venue">
        <div class="ect-list-venue  default-venue"><span class="ect-icon"><i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i></span> <span class="ect-venue-details ect-address"><a href="https://www.lagaleramagazine.es/?post_type=tribe_venue&amp;p=41948" title="Fundación CB">Fundación CB</a>,<span class="tribe-address"><span class="tribe-street-address">C/ Pablo Sorozábal, s/nº1,</span>          <br> <span class="tribe-locality">Badajoz</span><span class="tribe-delimiter">,</span><abbr class="tribe-region tribe-events-abbr" title="Badajoz">Badajoz</abbr><span class="tribe-postal-code">06006</span><span class="tribe-country-name">España</span></span>
          </span><span class="ect-google"><a class="tribe-events-gmap" href="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=C%2F+Pablo+Soroz%C3%A1bal%2C+s%2Fn%C2%BA1%2C+Badajoz+Badajoz+06006+Espa%C3%B1a" title="Click para ver mapa de Google" target="_blank">+ Google Map</a></span>
          <div class="ect-rate-area"><span class="ect-rate-icon"><i class="fa fa-money" aria-hidden="true"></i></span> <span class="ect-rate">Gratuito</span></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's work's mostly well but when I open an item and the text change to "Less details" but when I focus out the text didn't change to "More details" (the box text closed well). How I can fix it? Thanks.